# conversion for void* as a method argument

Tags: c++

For a method with an argument of void* is C++ employing static/reinterpret_cast to make the conversion or is there a different mechanism in play here?

```
void foo(void* p)
{
    // ... use p by casting it back to Base first, using static/reinterpret cast
}
Base* base(new Derived);
foo(base);       // at this exact line, is there a static/reinterpret_cast going on under the covers?
```

I am asking because it seems that on one hand the standard says that for c-style cast, C++ will go and try a C++ cast (static, reinterpret, const) until something that works is found. However I can't find a reasonable explanation as to what goes on when a method with a void* argument is called. On the face of thing there is no cast, so what happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language specification does not express the behavior in terms of `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` in this case. It just says that the pointer `base` is *implicitly converted* to `void *` type. Conversions that can be performed implicitly are called *standard conversions* in C++. Conversion of any object pointer type to `void *` is one of the standard conversions from *pointer conversions* category.

It is true that this is the same conversion that can be preformed explicitly by `static_cast`, but `static_cast` is completely irrelevant in this case. Standard conversions in C++ work "by themselves" without involving any specific cast operators under the cover.

In fact, it is the behavior of `static_cast` that is defined in terms of standard conversions for such cases, not the other way around.

Comment: And the key thing about a conversion from `T*` to `void*` is that the resulting `void*` must point to the start of the storage location of the `T` object - which is what you'd probably expect.  But I think it's important that the expected behavior is what's called out in the standard (because it's not always the case that standard requires expected behavior).

Comment: The other important property of conversion of `T*` to `void*` (where `T` is an object type) is that the conversion back to `T*` (which does require a static cast) will net the original value.

Comment: Considerations on the global usefulness of ()(void*) methods aside, how do you use p in foo()? You have to cast it back to a type. But if you cast it back, you have an implicit conversion at the caller and an explicit conversion on the callee side - an asymmetric situation. Don't you have to assume in that case, that the "implicit" conversion that took place was really a static cast?

Comment: @ask: Yes, it is an asymmetric situation. And that's one of the very, _very_ many reasons C++ users avoid casting random pointers to `void*`s unless they have exhausted all other options.